# Add a function for mysql via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have function as below to be added into mysql db I have try it via phpMyAdmin but it gives me no indication whether added or not and when I try to run the function give error the function does not exist. Anything I am missing here?

```
DELIMITER // 

CREATE FUNCTION GISWithin(pt POINT, mp MULTIPOLYGON) RETURNS INT(1) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 

DECLARE str, xy TEXT; 
DECLARE x, y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, m, xinters DECIMAL(16, 13) DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE p, pb, pe INT DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT MBRWithin(pt, mp) INTO p; 
IF p != 1 OR ISNULL(p) THEN 
RETURN p; 
END IF; 

SELECT X(pt), Y(pt), ASTEXT(mp) INTO x, y, str; 
SET str = REPLACE(str, 'POLYGON((',''); 
SET str = REPLACE(str, '))', ''); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, ','); 

SET pb = 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str); 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p1x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p1y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
SET str = CONCAT(str, xy, ','); 

WHILE pe > 0 DO 
SET xy = SUBSTRING(str, pb, pe - pb); 
SET p = INSTR(xy, ' '); 
SET p2x = SUBSTRING(xy, 1, p - 1); 
SET p2y = SUBSTRING(xy, p + 1); 
IF p1y < p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y > m THEN 
IF p1y > p2y THEN SET m = p1y; ELSE SET m = p2y; END IF; 
IF y <= m THEN 
IF p1x > p2x THEN SET m = p1x; ELSE SET m = p2x; END IF; 
IF x <= m THEN 
IF p1y != p2y THEN 
SET xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x; 
END IF; 
IF p1x = p2x OR x <= xinters THEN 
SET counter = counter + 1; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
SET p1x = p2x; 
SET p1y = p2y; 
SET pb = pe + 1; 
SET pe = LOCATE(',', str, pb); 
END WHILE; 

RETURN counter % 2; 

END; 

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 7):

You have set your delimiter to `//`, but your final `END` statement terminates with `;`, so the function is likely never created.

Try changing it to:

```
END//
```

**UPDATE:**

phpMyAdmin doesn't respect or know about DELIMITER because it is a MySQL CLI client command only. [According to this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126320,247753#msg-247753), there's a text box in phpMyAdmin to set the delimiter. Enter your // in there and remove the DELIMITER statements from your code.

Comment: I have tried end// I get this error. There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 10
STR: //
SQL: ELIMITER // 

CREATE FUNCTION GISWithin(pt POINT, mp MULTIPOLYGON) RETURNS INT(1) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 

DECLARE str, xy TEXT;

Comment: Looks like phpMyAdmin doesn't respect or know about `DELIMITER` because it is a MySQL CLI client command only.  According to this post, there's a text box in phpMyAdmin to set the delimiter. Enter your `//` in there and remove the `DELIMITER` statements from your code. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126320,247753#msg-247753

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `//` after `end`

Comment: Ok I checked ready I miss the D letter of my previous error. I have tried again putting end // but same no confirmation message on the function creating? When I press Go is just come with the message loading and that's it